Unstructured partition_pdf can't find tesseract
I am trying to use the partition_pdf function from Unstructured with strategy="hi_res" on a Windows machine.  The function keeps failing because it can't find the path to the Tesseract executable.  I am able to set this path if I use pytesseract directly, but I don't know how to set it in Unstructured.  Anyone know how to resolve this?  System is Windows 10.
Full command:
from unstructured.partition.pdf import partition_pdf

fname = "test_file.pdf"

elements = partition_pdf(filename=fname, strategy="hi_res")

Error:
...
File ~\AppData\Local\anaconda3\envs\unstructured\lib\site-packages\unstructured_pytesseract\pytesseract.py:453, in get_tesseract_version()
    446     output = subprocess.check_output(
    447         [tesseract_cmd, '--version'],
    448         stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,
    449         env=environ,
    450         stdin=subprocess.DEVNULL,
    451     )
    452 except OSError:
--> 453     raise TesseractNotFoundError()
    455 raw_version = output.decode(DEFAULT_ENCODING)
    456 str_version, *_ = raw_version.lstrip(string.printable[10:]).partition(' ')

TesseractNotFoundError: tesseract is not installed or it's not in your PATH. See README file for more information.


You can add the path to the code in unstructured library that calls the code, the file that you are looking for is in unstructured/partition/utils/ocr_models/tesseract_ocr.py. In this case, the full path will be ~/AppData/Local/anaconda3/envs/unstructured/lib/site-packages/unstructured/partition/utils/ocr_models/tesseract_ocr.py
One of the ways to add is before the class OCRAgentTesseract(OCRAgent), so the end result will be something like this:
from unstructured.logger import logger
from unstructured.partition.utils.config import env_config`
from unstructured.partition.utils.constants import (
    IMAGE_COLOR_DEPTH,
    TESSERACT_MAX_SIZE,
    TESSERACT_TEXT_HEIGHT,
    Source,
)
from unstructured.partition.utils.ocr_models.ocr_interface import OCRAgent
from unstructured.utils import requires_dependencies

if TYPE_CHECKING:
    from unstructured_inference.inference.elements import TextRegion
    from unstructured_inference.inference.layoutelement import (
        LayoutElement,
    )

unstructured_pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r"<path_to_tesseract>" <- add here

class OCRAgentTesseract(OCRAgent):

